# name generalized invariant tensors

Tags: rt.representation-theory, terminology, invariant-theory

When $V$ is the defining representation of a matrix group $G$, it is common to refer to $Hom_G(\mathbb C, \otimes^r V)$ as the space of invariant tensors.

Is there a similar (well established) name for $Hom_G(W, \otimes^r V)$, when $W$ and $V$ are arbitrary representations of $G$?

Comment: I'd say that if $W$ is irreducible this can be viewed as the $W$-isotypical component of the representation $\otimes^r V$. The invariant tensors are just the 'trivial' isotypical component.

Comment: Assuming $W$ is irreducible, the $W$-isotypical component of a polynomial representation of $G$ is classically known as "covariants" (with appropriate nomenclature reflecting $W$). I believe I have also seen "tensor covariants" used for the case you are interested in.

Comment: If $W$ is the defining representation then in the 19th century an element of this space would be called a "covariant". If $W$ is a more general irreducible representation then "mixed concomitant" would be the expression used classically.

Comment: So "invariant tensor" should actually be "covariant"?

Comment: In the 19th century they only discussed polynomial invariant theory. Tensor invariant theory started in the 20th century with Brauer, Weyl, Littlewood.